# Create a new array with SecurityGroupIds instead of SecurityGroupNames with Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, loops, ansible, aws-security-group

I am relatively new to Ansible and I am struggling to understand how to perform the following scenario:
I have an array with AWS security group names looking like this

```
['Security-Group-Name1', 'SecurityGroup-Name2', 'SecurityGroup-Name3']
```

However, what I want is to have an array of SecurityGroupIds. Using Ansible I have the ec2_group_info as an option to retrieve information about a security group. So far so good ...

Now comes my question. I need to loop through the above array using **ec2_group_info**, set the name of the security group I need and return the retrieved Id into a new array so in the end I have something like this.

```
['Security-Group-Id1', 'SecurityGroup-Id2', 'SecurityGroup-Id3']
```

I know I need to use a loop with sort of a dynamic index. But it is not really clear to me how to do this in Ansible.

I am aware of the latest loop section of Ansible Docs and I find them more than confusing...
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html

**Edit:**

This is the current code which works as needed:

```
- name: Installing pip if not existing on host
  pip:
    name: boto3

- name: Get SecurityGroupId information
  ec2_group_info:
    filters:
      group_name: ['SG-One', 'SG-Two']
      vpc_id: 'vpc-id'
  register: my_groups

- set_fact:
    my_group_ids: '{{ my_groups.security_groups | map(attribute="group_id") | list }}'

- debug:
    msg: "{{ my_groups }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ my_group_ids }}"
```

This is the outcome:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************** 
ok: [localhost]

TASK [machine-provisioning : Installing pip if not existing on host] ************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [machine-provisioning : Get SecurityGroupId information] ************************* 
ok: [localhost]

TASK [machine-provisioning : set_fact] *********************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [machine-provisioning : debug] ***********************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
"msg": [
    "sg-00000000",
    "sg-11111111"
]
```

}

Comment: `group_name: "['SG-One', 'SG-Two']"` is not a `list`, it's a string containing python-y syntax; ironically, due to the way yaml works, if you just remove the outer `"` it will then _become_ a list

Comment: What I find extremely confusing about this is that I need to add outer " when using brackets for dynamic variables but I do not need it when referring to a list in yaml. 
Thanks I will try this.

Comment: Yes, you need to add the quotes because (deep sigh) jinja2 uses `{` as the opening character of its interpolation syntax, but that character is also legal yaml, so the yaml parser thinks `thing: {{ some_jinja_var }}` is `"thing": {}` but with a bogus body (since in JSON you cannot have `{ {`. You really should stop and read a tutorial, if you're getting jammed up this early in your ansible experience

Comment: If "null is the one billion dollar mistake," then Dag choosing to use jinja2 without customizing its variable and block syntax is ansible's "million dollar mistake"; they actually do allow you to [customize it for templates](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/template_module.html#parameter-variable_start_string), it's just ansible itself is stupid about it

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that this worked, so thanks a lot for your advice and I will start to read a bit tutorials to get a better understanding of how the syntax rules work, thanks again!

Comment: If you haven't yet seen, there is also `- debug: var: my_groups` which can be nicer on the eyes when you don't have any other text to include in `msg:` -- it's secretly doing exactly what you did under the covers, by changing to `msg: "{{ the_var }}"` but it's much nicer to read and more expressive

Comment: No, I didn't know about this, but its good advice, will use that if it is easier to read ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On that linked page about loops, you'll observe the use of [`register:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop), which is how you'd capture the result of that `ec2_group_info:` lookup, then use the [`map` jinja filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#map) to extract `map(attribute="group_id")` from the resulting list of results; you have to feed the output of `map` into the `list` filter, because `map` and a few others are python generators, and thus need a terminal action to materialize their data. The [`set_fact:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/set_fact_module.html) is how ansible does "assignment"

```yaml
- ec2_group_info:
    filters:
      group_name: '{{ the_group_names }}'
      vpc_id: '{{ my_vpc_id }}'
  register: my_groups
- set_fact:
    my_group_ids: '{{ my_groups.security_groups | map(attribute="group_id") | list }}'
```

yields:

```
ok: [localhost] => {"ansible_facts": {"my_group_ids": ["sg-0c5c277ed1edafb54", "sg-7597a123"]}, "changed": false}
```

Comment: Ok, let me recap so that I understand this correctly. When I pass an array into the_group_names it would return an object of information for each group_name and save this as an array value into my_groups. From there I would use set_fact and map(attribute="SecurityGroupId") to filter on SecurityGroupId information in that object and create an array out of this information which is saved into my_group_ids, do I understand this correctly?

Comment: that's what I would expect to happen, yes; your circumstances are a little unique in that `ec2_group_info` accepts an array and returns an array in its results, meaning you don't need the `with_items:` for this circumstance, as you normally would with more "single purpose" fact gathering tasks

Comment: That is interesting, alright, I will test this and see how it performs

Comment: Ok, I tested above, it does work when I use a single value in filters group_name such as group_name: "SG-Name1" but it does not work when I use several values in an array such as group_name: ['SG-Name1', 'SG-Name2', 'SG-Name3'] how would I need to write this that it works using an array?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63171594/edit) to show the actual playbook and its results, rather than attempting to put code in the comments (they're terrible for that). I just testing it locally and it did as I said, with the asterisk that I forgot to include the `vpc_id:` in the filters, which can affect the outcome